# formula for finding a square of a number

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, perfect-square

I need to display the squares of the numbers 1-10 using a for loop.  This is what I have so far.  I don't know what I am missing.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
        {                          
            Console.WriteLine(counter * counter);                
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The code is perfectly fine. It is producing the output as expected. Can you put a BreakPoint and see if it is getting executed?

Comment: One more question, how would I do 1 = sqaure and then 2 = square and so on

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Number :{0}, Square : {1}", counter,counter * counter);`

Comment: or else `Console.WriteLine(counter = (counter * counter));` . go with some tutorials http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
    {          
            Console.WriteLine(counter*counter);
    }
```

Comment: hmmm, for some reason I get no output

Comment: Show your full code after updates. I guess you have not removed if condition which is evaluating to false.

Comment: @Vinnie, enclose it in backticks ``Like: `code`, see?`` But only short snippets are appropriate for comments.

Comment: `code: for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
            {
                          
                Console.WriteLine(counter * counter);
                
            }

       
            Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: for some reason I had to restart visual studio and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at your code

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
{
   if ((counter * counter) == 0) // this will never evaluate to true
   {
       Console.WriteLine(counter);
   }
}
```

Since you are starting off with 1 your if condition is never true, so nothing would be printed

you just need to use `counter * counter` printed in your for loop

or you can use `Math.Pow(counter, 2.0)` to get your squares

Comment: +1 for [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For an integer `counter` having any value other than `0`, `counter * counter` will *never* evaluate to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

if ((counter * counter) == 0)   This will not satisfy for any value..Try if ((counter * counter) != 0) ..Try this..

Answer (score 0):

Since you start with 1, that counter * counter can not be 0. So, having that in mind, here's the whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(i * i);
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure that this was helpful.